# Input hidden controlar checkbox

Tags: javascript

É possível ter um evento que consoante o change de uma hidden input faça determinadas ações?

tenho isso feito para uma `checkbox`, mas não estou a conseguir fazer o inverso...

```
function getBitCheckbox(checkboxElem) {
    console.log(checkboxElem.id);

    if (checkboxElem.id == 'checkbox_bitInativo') {
        if (checkboxElem.checked) {
            // set bit Anulado a true
            $("#bitInativo").val(1);
        } else {
            //set bit Anulado a false
            $("#bitInativo").val(0);
        }
    }

    if (checkboxElem.id == 'checkbox_bitAprovado') {
        if (checkboxElem.checked) {
            // set bit Aprovado a true
            $("#bitAprovado").val(1);
        } else {
            //set bit Aprovado a false
            $("#bitAprovado").val(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá! Quando escreves _"change de uma hidden input"_ podes explicar também como é que o input muda? Ele é alterado por JavaScript presumo... é código teu ou de terceiros?

Comment: Boa tarde,

Estou a atualizar os dados via ajax e a preencher as hidden inputs dessa forma. 

A minha necessidade prende-se com o facto de consoante o valor que esteja na input possa definir o estado de uma checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi bem a pergunta, mas você quer saber como ativar automaticamente um evento ao se alterar o valor de um input via script, é isso?
Naturalmente JavaScript não ativa nenhum evento, mas você pode chamar esse evento logo após mudar o valor, por exemplo:

Defino aqui o elemento que invoca foo quando seu valor é alterado -

```
<input id="bitAprovado" type="hidden" onchange="foo(this)">
```

Então, para ativar o mesmo evento ao se alterar o valor via script, eu uso -

```
$("#bitAprovado").val(1).change();
```

**--Edit--**

Existe uma segunda alternativa chamada MutationObserver, que serve para registrar alterações pelo script

```
let bitAprovado = document.getElementById('bitAprovado');
let observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => foo(mutations[0].target));
observer.observe(bitAprovado, {attributes: true});
```

Neste caso o evento só ativaria ao se mudar o valor via script. Também não há a necessidade de chamar .change() depois de alterar o valor.